# Homebrew will not begin to install on Mojave 10.14.2

Tags: python, xcode, bash, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install home-brew on my Mac because my linux partition messed up, in the mean time I was trying to install python using

> $ brew install python

then it gave the error

> -bash: brew: command not found

I'm assuming that with the Mac update brew became unusable so I tried using multiple variations of

> $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

After this didn't work, I did some digging and found out you had to use Xcode and command line tools. I couldn't use the command:

> $ xcode-select --install

because it returned with the same-ish response,

> -bash: xcode-select: command not found

So I went and downloaded it manually. After this I assumed I had done it. Still, it returned the same error when I tried to use;

> $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
>
> -bash: curl: command not found

Are there any solutions?

P.S. Here are some things I tried incase you can't understand my gibberish

> $ python --version
>
> -bash: python: command not found
>
> $ brew doctor
>
> -bash: brew: command not found
>
> $ brew install python
>
> -bash: brew: command not found
>
> $ xcode-select --install
>
> -bash: xcode-select: command not found
>
> $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
>
> -bash: curl: command not found $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
>
> -bash: curl: command not found

Comment: Why not [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php)?

Comment: That still doesn't fix the issue no matter what pkg installer I use. Even if I were to run that it'd still return an error with Xcodebuild instead. Its more like terminal doesn't want to run anything at all. I don't know if it's 10.14.2 or what.

Comment: Did you install `Xcode` or the command-line tools?

Comment: Both. I donwloaded Xcode then I had to manually install command-line tools.